# Generic type used as more specific generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have Class1 with generic T1, and Class2 with generic T2. Generic T2 has constraints while T1 doesn't.

Now within Class1, I want to check if T1 matches the constraint of T2, and if it does use it with Class2.

Is this possible? How?

```
public class Class1<T1> {
    public static object GetObj() {
        if (typeof(SomeBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T1))) {
            // I know that T1 is a subclass of SomeBaseClass, and want to create a Class2 object using it
            return new Class2<T1>();  // this doesn't work. How can I "force" the compiler to treat T1 as a T2, like casting?
        }
    }
}

public class Class2<T2> where T2 : SomeBaseClass {
}
```

Edit: Reflection unfortunately is not a good solution because of the overhead, this gets called a lot.

Comment: Pretty sure it's going to be reflection. The compiler isn't going to believe that `T1` meets the constraint unless you can prove it at compile time.

Comment: The reason that this is hard to do is that it's a bad idea. It breaks SOLID principles. What are you actually trying to do? I bet there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AakashM said I guess using reflection is the only way:

```
public class Class1<T1>
{
    public static object GetObj()
    {
        if (typeof(SomeBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T1)))
        {
            var genericType = typeof(Class2<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T1));
            return Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
        }

        // throw Exception or return null
    }
}
```

#### Update

Following your comment, if reflection is too slow you might be able to use compiled expressions:

```
public class Class1<T1>
{
    private static readonly Func<T1> _factory;

    static Class1() 
    {
        if (!typeof(SomeBaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T1)))
        {
            _factory = () => default(T1);
            return;
        }

        var ctor = typeof(T1).GetConstructor(Array.Empty<Type>());
        var newExpression = Expression.New(ctor);

        _factory = Expression.Lambda<Func<T1>>(newExpression).Compile();
    }

    public static object GetObj()
    {
        return _factory();
    }
}
```

This solution creates a factory for each variant of `Class1` (for example `Class1<SomeSubClass>`, `Class1<SomeOtherSubClass>` and so on). Building the expression takes some time, but after that it is really fast.

I've run some tests to see how long it takes to create 1 million instances of `Class2` using the `GetObj()` method:

- best case (constraint added to `Class1`, simply return `new Class2<T1>()`): **4 ms**
- reflection (as shown in the original solution): **991 ms**
- using a compiled expression (as shown above): **26 ms**

As you can see the new solution is significantly faster than the previous one. However, if you are using a lot of different types for `T1` the performance improvement will be smaller or even nonexistent.

Comment: Unfortunately the overhead of reflection will be a problem because this is used a lot. Sorry I didn't mention it in the original post (edited now)

Comment: @tbkn23 I've updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: This is interesting, I wasn't familiar with these compiled expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, both T1 and T2 inherit from SomeBaseClass?
If yes then you should declare Class1 as

```
public class Class1<T1> where T1: SomeBaseClass
```

Comment: No, only T2 inherits from the base class

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements, you can use two different generic methods with the constraint on one:

```
public static object GetObj<T>() where T : SomeBaseClass => new Class2<T>();
public static object GetObjOther<T>() => <whatever you want as else>;
```

There is no statically typed way of achieving it with the same method as the type system needs to know at compile time; if you must have an if statement as described, the only other way is reflection as suggested in the answer from `fknx`.

The closer you can get to your requirement is if you add an argument of the specific type:

```
public static object GetObj<T>(T obj) where T : SomeBaseClass => new Class2<T>();
public static object GetObj<T>(Class2<T> objc) where T : SomeBaseClass => <whatever you want as else>;
```

Of course this is really confusing and possibly wrong without knowing the context.

Comment: I was aiming for something like this, however it's a generic class (T is defined for the class not for the method). Can this be done with classes?

Comment: You can only if do not create two methods with the same signature. Maybe you can define one with a more strict constraint on the class's constraint, but I don't have VS with me now so I can't test. Can you put a usage in the question so it's easier to understand the context?

Comment: Something like: GetObj<TSpecific>() where TSpecific : T, BaseClass, so you say that it must be T from the class and ALSO BaseClass. Not sure it works (It's early to think it through) but maybe using interfaces it might.